# RoleManager, UserManager datetime2 exception while trying to seed database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime, sql-server-2012, asp.net-identity-2

I get the famous

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

exception at `manager.Create(role);` when trying to seed the database. It happens regardless I use Db initializer class or Migrations to Seed my db.

```
if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "AppAdmin"))
        {
            using (var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context))
            using (var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store))
            {
                var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "AppAdmin" };

                manager.Create(role);
            }
        }
        if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "SampleUser"))
        {
            using( var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context) )
            using (var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store))
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "SampleUser", PhoneNumber = "0797697898", Email = "adr@gmail.com" };

                manager.Create(user, "ChangeItAsap!");
                manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "AppAdmin");
            }
```

I know the problem is SQL Server datetime cannot contain default(DateTime) value since it only can hold dates after 1753/1/1 but I don't have control on Identity Framework internals so I can't put additional attributes on problematic properties to turn them to datetime2. Also, I might not event want to, I just want to have some initial users and roles created in my database.

After inspecting Db schema I see the only date used is LockoutEndDateUtc in AspNetUsers, but (as I mentioned earlier) exception happens before even I try to add any users!

Any suggestions?

(SQL Server 2012, asp-mvc-5-2-2, entity-framework-6-1-3, identity-framework 2-1, Visual Studio 2013)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

helped but that is not a solution I was looking for...